# download excel file from assets (vue.js)

Tags: excel, vue.js, download, href

I want to `download` a `excel file` from my `vue.js`-project.

I've tried as following:

```
<template>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <a href="./assets/template.xlsx" target="_blank">Download file</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

But I always get this `ERROR`:

[image]

Could anyone give me a clue how to solve this error? - It don't has to be solved with an `<a>-tag` it could also be a `button` or something else.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the path to the file is incorrect. The `./` in `"./assets/template.xlsx"` implies the excel file is in the same directory as your Vue component.  I doubt this is the case. Try a relative path from your project root.

It's probably more accurate to use:

```html
<a href="src/assets/template.xlsx" target="_blank">Download file</a>
```